# Importing workitem to TFS, work item type not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs

I'm looking at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130322.aspx) but the code breaks on the line

`WorkItemType workItemType = teamProject.WorkItemTypes["User Story"];`

with the error

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.WorkItemTypeDeniedOrNotExistException'
>   occurred in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll
>
> Additional information: TF201077: The work item type User Story cannot
>   be found. It may have been renamed or destroyed.

Where/what exactly should "User Story" be?

Do I need to import an XML document to my solution? Is the TFS server I'm connecting to not configured right for the way I'm trying to access it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Template are you using? on your TFS Team Project.

As stated in that web page you need to be using

> For example, you might create a user story as defined in MSF for Agile
>   software development for Visual Studio ALM.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. I hadn't set up the TFS myself but after your comment I was able to figure out where the WIT name was.